# CSS Grid | Gridstack.js -- make one grid-stack-item widget have locked aspectRatio

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I use gridstack (https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js/tree/master) which uses jQueryUI's "Resizable" behaviour.  I am trying to set aspectRatio: true on only one of the widgets (tiles) in the grid but there is no obvious way to do this.

Here's the js to initialize gridstack:

```
grid = $(".grid-stack").gridstack
    ({
        width:  12,
        height: 9,
        animate: true,
        always_show_resize_handle: /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
        draggable:
        {
            handle: ".box-title-bar"
        },
        resizable:
        {
            aspectRatio: "true",
            handles: "se"
        }
    }).data("gridstack");
```

Setting resizable: { aspectRatio: "true" } sets it for all tiles in the grid; however, I can't figure out how to set this for only one of the tiles/widgets.